# Can the prefix re- be added to nouns?

Tags: morphology, affixes

I am a little confused about what affix to add first to the stem "elect". The word is re-election. If I add the suffix *-ion* first, then it turns the verb into a noun. The affix '*re-*' attaches best to verbs (if I'm not mistaken). Should I just attach the prefix first then?

Comment: If _re_- can be added to the verbs that the nouns come from, then they can appear on the nouns that are derived from them. _Re-elect_ is a verb, so _re-election_ is the derived noun.

Comment: so it doesnt matter which one i add first? or i could check in a corpus which on is the most common?

Comment: _Re_- is a verbal prefix. The _re_- appears on the verb. And the verb gets made into a noun. There's no "first" -- this isn't what happens when you talk, it's what happened when the verb was borrowed from Latin.

Answer (score 1):

The first test you should apply is whether *re-* can be added to a noun and give another noun – **re-tree*, **re-pig* and so on should persuade you that *re-* does not attach to nouns. Second is to verify that *re-* attaches to verb, e.g. *re-take, re-think, re-elect*. Then when faced with a derivation from noun to verb or verb to noun, if on the *surface* you find a word of one category X which takes an affix that only attaches to category Y, and if the word also has an affix that converts a Y to an X, then you should assume that the restricted affix is added to the category Y stem *first*, and then Y changes to X.

Words like "first", "then" are used by linguists in different ways — either literally, meaning in time (i.e. there is a claim about processing) or else in terms of lower versus higher levels of attachment in a structural tree (in case you want to avoid any implications about processing). To really put your theory to the test, you should also try to find newly-generated forms, like "re-macadamize" or even "re-pre-macadamize", which can't reasonably be accused of being historical archaisms (unless you build roads for a living). "Re-think" is a good example since unlike *re-elect*, it couldn't have been pre-constructed in Latin.